# Is there a way to differentiate the materialised view from common views in a schema

Tags: sql, database, view, hiveql, materialized-views

How do i differentiate between views that are common from the materialised views in a schema that I have?

I am trying to differentiate views in hive.

Comment: You'll need to tag the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: By looking them up in the dictionary...

Comment: I have added the HiveQL tag based on the OPs update.